# .NETStandard multi-targeting library packages gives me CS0234 error on Netstandard 2.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard

So I have to refactor a project from `.NET Framework` to `Net Standard`, the `Net Standard` version is `2.0` and my `.NET Framework` version is `4.7.2`.
I am using multi targeting in my csproj because I still need some functionalities from `.NET Framework` that don't exist in `.NET Standard`, for example, `System.Runtime.Remoting`.
I thought that multi targeting would solve my problem of `Net Standard` not having the package, but it is giving me this error:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Remoting' does not exist in
> the namespace 'System.Runtime' (are you missing an assembly
> reference?)   Project.Standard (netstandard2.0)

This is my Csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
        <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net472'">
        <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Remoting" />
    </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

For some reason my code isn't able to target the `.NET Framework` when it needs to or am I missing something in my Csproj?

Comment: You are trying to use functionality (Remoting) that simply doesn't exist in Standard. There's no point in multi-targeting a library if one of those targets is just going to `return null` or throw `NotSupportedException` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSPROJ file is setup properly. I am going to assume there is some source code that is referencing the assembly.

You need to figure out where in your source code you are referencing it and surround it in a directive that looks like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void TestMe()
    {
#if NET472
        var test = new System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.SoapAttribute();
#endif
    }
}
```

This will ensure it only is visible when it's compiled for .NET Framework 4.7.2 and not .NET Standard.